# Parse XML using T-SQL and XQUERY - Searching for specific values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have some properties of an application being passed to me in XML form. I need to parse out the property by name and assign the value to the appropriate column in my database.

I am currently parsing it out in a SSIS script component but it takes way to long to complete. I was hoping there would be an easy solution for this using XQUERY, but I cannot find what I am looking for.

Here is an example of the xml I am receiving:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <name>DISMISS_SETTING</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>SHOW_SETTING</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>DEFAULT_SETTING</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
</properties>
```

So, if I were looking at the first property element I would assign the value DEFAULT to my DISMISS_SETTING column in my database. Also, it's important to note the order and combinations of the values can come across in no specific order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to extract a value from your XML. Check for the name you want in a predicate in the XQuery expression.

```sql
select 
  @XML.value('(/properties/property[name = "DISMISS_SETTING"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as DISMISS_SETTING,
  @XML.value('(/properties/property[name = "SHOW_SETTING"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as SHOW_SETTING,
  @XML.value('(/properties/property[name = "DEFAULT_SETTING"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as DEFAULT_SETTING
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5044)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a TSQL solution and if I your result table should look like this shown on the schemat below:

```
| DISMISS_SETTING | SHOW_SETTING | DEFAULT_SETTING |
|-----------------|--------------|-----------------|
| DEFAULT         | DEFAULT      | DEFAULT         |
```

you should use set of scripts I'll describe in a moment. Initially you need to create dynamic stored procedure which builds dynamic queries - it gives you the possibility to insert your data into table under such columns, which names aren't known until runtime (the time of your XML parsing):

```
create procedure mysp_update (@table_name nvarchar(50), @column_name nvarchar(50), @column_value nvarchar(50))
as
begin
    declare @rows_count int
    declare @query nvarchar(500)
    declare @parm_definition nvarchar(100)

    -- Get rows count in your table using sp_executesql and an output parameter        
    set @query = N'select @rows_count = count(1) from ' +  quotename(@table_name)
    exec sp_executesql @query, N'@rows_count INT OUTPUT', @rows_count OUTPUT

    -- If no rows - insert the first one, else - update existing
    if @rows_count = 0
        set @query = N'insert into ' + quotename(@table_name) + N'(' + quotename(@column_name) + N') values (@column_value)'        
    else
        set @query = N'update ' + quotename(@table_name) + N'set ' + quotename(@column_name) + N' = @column_value' 

    set @parm_definition = N'@column_value nvarchar(50)'
    exec sp_executesql @query, @parm_definition, @column_value = @column_value
end
go
```

Next, use this XQuery / SQL statement to extract (from XML) information you're looking for:

```
-- Define XML object based on which insert statement will be later created   
declare @data xml = N'<properties>
    <property>
        <name>DISMISS_SETTING</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>SHOW_SETTING</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>DEFAULT_SETTING</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
</properties>'

-- Declare temporary container
declare @T table(id int identity, name nvarchar(50), value nvarchar(50))

-- Push the extracted nodes values into it
insert into @T(name, value)
select
    x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)'),
    x.value(N'(value)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)')
from
    @data.nodes(N'/properties/property') AS XTbl(x)
```

After that, extracted pairs of data *[name, value]* are stored in table variable `@T`. Finally, iterate over such temporary metadata and insert *values* in appropriate *column names* of your main table:

```
declare @name nvarchar(50), @value nvarchar(50), @current_id int = 1

-- Fetch first row
select @name = name, @value = value 
from @T where id = @current_id

while @@rowcount = 1
begin
    -- Execute SP here (btw: SP cannot be executed from select statement)
    exec mysp_update N'TableName', @name, @value

    -- Fetch next row
    set @current_id = @current_id + 1

    select @name = name, @value = value 
    from @T where id = @current_id  
end
```

Presented solution allows you to have mutable number of nodes in the XML, provided without any specific order.

Note that the logic responsible for data extraction from XML and insertion to the main table, can be wrapped within additional stored procedure e.g. `mysp_xml_update (@data xml)` and then executed in following clean way: `exec mysp_xml_update N'<properties>....</properties>`.

Nevertheless, try the code yourself using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16464).

**UPDATE:**

As requested in the comment - one big update should be executed instead of sequentially updating column by column. For that purpose `mysp_update` should be modified e.g. in following way:

```
create type HashTable as table(name nvarchar(50), value nvarchar(50))
go

create procedure mysp_update (@table_name nvarchar(50), @set HashTable readonly)
as
begin  
    -- Concatenate names and values (to be passed to insert statement below)
    declare @columns varchar(max)
    select @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ', '') + quotename(name) from @set
    declare @values varchar(max)
    select @values = COALESCE(@values + ', ', '') + quotename(value, '''') from @set

    -- Remove previous values
    declare @query nvarchar(500)
    set @query = N'delete from ' + quotename(@table_name)
    -- Insert new values to the table
    exec sp_executesql @query
    set @query = N'insert into ' + quotename(@table_name) + N'(' + @columns + N') values (' + @values + N')'    
    exec sp_executesql @query
end
go
```

Comment: Jaroslaw, this is great. Is there an easy way to do this without using the XML variable? For example, I have rows upon rows of XML to process.

Comment: @Dave L. Hi, nice to hear that. Unfortunately I'm afraid I don't really understand the question in comment - can you elaborate a bit more what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: rather than processing one record at a time, is there a way to do this without having to iterate through each record in my database?

Comment: @Dave L. Ok you mean push all the data to the table at once, instead of updating sequentially column by column. It can be done - check update of the answer. I just chose simpler way - delete previous values and put the new ones instead of updating (simpler script). To get it all working together some additional cosmetic changes have to be done (e.g. `declare @T table(id int identity, name nvarchar(50), value nvarchar(50))` need to be changed into `declare @T HashTable` etc.), but it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by extracting the name and value from the xml and pivoting about the name. However, you cannot do this with arbitrary names found at query time. If you need that, you're probably better off removing the PIVOT and just using the name and value columns provided by the inner query.

```
DECLARE @xml xml

SET @xml = N'<properties>
    <property>
        <name>DISMISS_SETTING</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>SHOW_SETTING</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>DEFAULT_SETTING</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
</properties>'

SELECT     [DISMISS_SETTING], [SHOW_SETTING], [DEFAULT_SETTING]
FROM       (
                SELECT     properties.property.value(N'./name[1]', N'nvarchar(MAX)') AS propertyName
                         , properties.property.value(N'./value[1]', N'nvarchar(MAX)') AS propertyValue
                FROM       @xml.nodes(N'/properties/property') AS properties(property)
           ) AS properties
           PIVOT (MIN(propertyValue) FOR propertyName IN ([DISMISS_SETTING], [SHOW_SETTING], [DEFAULT_SETTING])) AS settings
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to refresh my existing answer (just for curiosity of alternatives and educational purposes). I pushed another one to keep both versions and preserve the possibility of tracking the parts which were improved:

1. Update of the first approach - sequential insert/update for each column (usage
   of cursor, removal of redundant temporary table):

   ```
   create procedure mysp_update (@table_name nvarchar(50), @column_name nvarchar(50), @column_value nvarchar(50))
   as
   begin
       set nocount on;
       declare @rows_count int
       declare @query nvarchar(500)
       declare @parm_definition nvarchar(100) = N'@column_value nvarchar(50)'        

       -- Update the row if it exists
       set @query = N'update ' + quotename(@table_name) + N'set ' + quotename(@column_name) + N' = @column_value'   
       exec sp_executesql @query, @parm_definition, @column_value = @column_value        
       -- Insert the row if the update statement failed
       if (@@rowcount = 0)
       begin
           set @query = N'insert into ' + quotename(@table_name) + N'(' + quotename(@column_name) + N') values (@column_value)'  
           exec sp_executesql @query, @parm_definition, @column_value = @column_value
       end
   end
   go

   create procedure mysp_xml_update (@table_name nvarchar(50), @data xml)
   as
   begin
       set nocount on;             
       declare @name nvarchar(50), @value nvarchar(50)

       -- Declare optimized cursor (fast_forward specifies forward_only, read_only cursor with performance optimizations enabled)
       declare mycursor cursor fast_forward
       for select
           x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)'),
           x.value(N'(value)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)')
       from
           @data.nodes(N'/properties/property') AS xtbl(x)

           open mycursor
           fetch next from mycursor into @name, @value 
           while @@fetch_status = 0
           begin       
               -- Execute SP here (btw: SP cannot be executed from select statement)
               exec mysp_update @table_name, @name, @value        
               -- Get the next row
               fetch next from mycursor into @name, @value
           end 
       close mycursor;
       deallocate mycursor;
   end
   go
   ```
2. Update of the second approach - bulk insert/update:

   ```
   create procedure mysp_xml_update (@table_name nvarchar(50), @data xml)
   as
   begin
       set nocount on;             
       declare @name nvarchar(50), @value nvarchar(50)

       -- Declare optimized cursor (fast_forward specifies forward_only, read_only cursor with performance optimizations enabled)
       declare mycursor cursor fast_forward
       for select
           x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)'),
           x.value(N'(value)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)')
       from
           @data.nodes(N'/properties/property') AS xtbl(x)

       declare @insert_statement nvarchar(max) = N'insert into ' + quotename(@table_name) + N' ($columns$) values (''$values$)'
       declare @update_statement nvarchar(max) = N'update ' + quotename(@table_name) + N' set $column$=''$value$'

       open mycursor
       fetch next from mycursor into @name, @value 
       while @@fetch_status = 0
       begin               
           set @insert_statement = replace(@insert_statement, '$columns$', quotename(@name) + ',$columns$')
           set @insert_statement = replace(@insert_statement, '$values$', @value + ''',''$values$')
           set @update_statement = replace(@update_statement, '$column$', quotename(@name))
           set @update_statement = replace(@update_statement, '$value$', @value + ''',$column$=''$value$')
           fetch next from mycursor into @name, @value
       end
       close mycursor;
       deallocate mycursor;

       set @insert_statement = replace(@insert_statement, ',$columns$', '')
       set @insert_statement = replace(@insert_statement, ',''$values$', '')
       set @update_statement = replace(@update_statement, ',$column$=''$value$', '')

       -- Update the row if it exists  
       exec sp_executesql @update_statement      
       -- Insert the row if the update statement failed
       if (@@rowcount = 0)
       begin          
           exec sp_executesql @insert_statement
       end
   end
   go
   ```
3. **And final, completely new, third approach** (dynamic bulk merge with pivot, no loops, no cursors):

   ```
   create procedure mysp_xml_update (@table_name nvarchar(50), @data xml)
   as
   begin
       set nocount on;     
       declare @columns nvarchar(max), @scolumns nvarchar(max), @kvp nvarchar(max)='', @query nvarchar(max)
       select @columns = coalesce(@columns + ',', '') + quotename(x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)')),
              @scolumns = coalesce(@scolumns + ',', '') + 's.' + quotename(x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)')),
              @kvp = @kvp + quotename(x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)')) + '=s.' 
                          + quotename(x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)')) + ','
       from @data.nodes(N'/properties/property') as xtbl(x)   
       select @kvp = left(@kvp, len(@kvp)-1)

       set @query = '
   merge ' + quotename(@table_name) + ' t
   using 
   (
       select ' + @columns + ' from 
       (
           select props.x.value(N''./name[1]'', N''nvarchar(50)'') as name,
                  props.x.value(N''./value[1]'', N''nvarchar(50)'') as value
           from @data.nodes(N''/properties/property'') as props(x)
       ) properties
       pivot 
       (
           min(value) for name in (' + @columns + ')
       ) settings
   ) s (' + @columns + ')
   on (1=1)
   when matched then 
       update set ' + @kvp + '
   when not matched then
       insert (' + @columns + ') 
       values (' + @scolumns + ');'    

       exec sp_executesql @query, N'@data xml', @data = @data
   end
   go
   ```

The usage is following:

```
exec mysp_xml_update N'mytable', N'<properties>
                                       <property>
                                           <name>DEFAULT_SETTING</name>
                                           <value>NEW DEFAULT 3</value>
                                       </property>
                                       <property>
                                           <name>SHOW_SETTING</name>
                                           <value>NEW DEFAULT 2</value>
                                       </property>
                                   </properties>'
```